# Improved MySQL interface

Tags: terminal, mysql

Is there a MySQL terminal prompt that supports things like tab-completion and history? The standard one that comes with MySQL doesn't have those features

Comment: Usually, `mysql` is built with readline capabilities, which includes all the things you mention. What operating system are you on, how did you install MySQL, and what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak from Linux experience, but the MySQL command line tool is chock full of options, including the two that you mention.

Tab completion is as simple as pressing the Tab key to expand database, table, and column names. From the MySQL docs:

> To complete a name, enter the first part and press Tab. If the name is
>   unambiguous, mysql completes it. Otherwise, you can press Tab again to
>   see the possible names that begin with what you have typed so far.
>   Completion does not occur if there is no default database.

Tab completion is enabled by default, however, it can be turned off by adding `no-auto-rehash` to the `[mysql]` section in your my.cnf file. It can also be disabled by passing the `-A` flag. So make sure you're not using any of those settings if you want tab completion turned on. If all else fails just type `rehash` at the mysql prompt after selecting a database.

As far as history... MySQL saves every query you execute in $MYSQL_HISTFILE, which defaults to ~/.mysql_history. Simply, pressing the Up and Down arrows will scroll through your history. If you want more advanced searching, mysql is compiled with the GNU readline library so all you need to do is type `ctl-r` and you can then perform a reverse history keyword search.

For more information check out:

[The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

[The GNU Readline Library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html)